# How to wait to perform an action after button click?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

As a beginner in Android programming, I don't really master the use of the threads and the **Handler()** function. After clicking on a button, I'd like to call a first method **startProjection()** then wait a few seconds before call a second method **stopProjection**().

By reading some topics about the question, I built this code, able to perform the first call but not the second :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // some code

    // start projection
    Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    startButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startProjection();

            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    stopProjection();
                }
            }, 7000);
        }
    });
```

The Build Gradle works correctly but when I finally click on the Button nothing happens. It seems that the handler doesn't work correctly. Is there anyway to perform these actions in the same **onClick()** method ?

EDIT : Previously the two methods were called separately buy using two buttons (and it works !), but I really want to use a single button.

Comment: This code is correct, what is your error?

Comment: **Handler handler = new Handler(), on every onClick() call** would probably allocate a new Handler for you in every button click. Make a Handler a global variable? See the differences you get in that case?

Comment: When the **stopProjection()** method ends, the app closes itself and the following messages appear on the Android Monitor :

E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
W/MediaProjectionManagerService: Failed to notify media projection has stopped

Comment: I try to make a Handler a global variable and I tell you. Thank you for the quick answers !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want to check if you have any specific reason to have stopProjection() function in a seperate thread. May be the following might work fine :

```
startProjection();
Thread.sleep(7000);
stopProjection();
```

Comment: I've already tried this one but each time an error of UnhandledExceptionEventHandler occured.